# Cassandra soft deletes on tables with only partial partition key known

Tags: cassandra

I have multiple tables with a combination of A, B, C entities as part of partition keys.

Table 1: columns A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H
Primary key ((A, B, C, Date), D, E)
rows-> A1, B1, C1, 07-09-2020, D1, E1 ....
A1, B1, C1, 07-10-2020, D1, E1 ....
A1, B2, C1, 07-10-2020, D2, E1 ....
.....

Table 2: columns A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H
Primary key ((B, C, Created_timestamp, A), D, E)
rows-> B1, C1, 07-09-2020 05:02:01Z, A1, D1, E1 ....
B1, C1, 07-10-2020 02:02:01Z, A1, D1, E1 ....
B2, C1, 07-10-2020 06:02:01Z, A1, D2, E1 ....
.....

Table 3: columns A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H
Primary Key ((B, A), C)
rows -> B1, A1, C1 ...
B2, A1, C2 ...
....

Table 4: columns A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H
Primary Key ((F, C), A)
rows  -> F1, C1, A1 ...
F1, C2, A1 ...
....

Now let's say if A1 is to be deleted in the system then all rows corresponding to A1 in all the tables should be marked as deleted (no TTL is to be used).

P.S - By pointing to above tables all I wanted to show was the position of A varies in the partition key and as well as in the primary key as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

**When deleting record for `Table 1`, at least the values of column `A,B,C` are known. So I think you need another 2 look up tables to achieve it**

- Lookup Table for `Table 2`

  Columns - `A, B, C,D, E, Created_timestamp`

  Primary key - `((A, B, C), Created_timestamp, D, E)`
- Lookup Table for `Table 4`

  Columns - `F, C, A`

  Primary key - `((A, C), F)`
- Once you have fetched the primary keys for `table 2` and `table 4`, you have the primary keys for them to delete it,